# SQL Server losts and shows error 26 after random time

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

I have a Windows Server 2012 as server, which have SQL Server 2008 R2 where our database is stored.

We have another 5 PC's installed with Windows 7 64-bit, which are run under domain of above server, they are also installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

We successfully connected SQL Server. But during after some work they loss connectivity from server and show SQL network related instance error 26 on random time and random client. LAN works perfectly. So what is the issue?

Comment: Do you have a firewall that disconnects the sessions after certain time of idling?

Comment: Also, what exactly is error 26?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx did any of solutions work for you?

Comment: No all firewall setting done , connection done succesfully but after some time it's disconnect. Before we have run this server on window 7 then sqlserver work correctly but after installing window server 2012 this issue happen